# Number of possible arrays such that adjacent elements have difference atmost 1

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

You know that an array has n integers between 1 and m, and the difference between two adjacent values is at most 1.

Given a description of the array where some values may be unknown, your task is to count the number of arrays that match the description.

The unknown values will be given as "0" in the input array.
Give the number of arrays modulo 1e9+7

The problem could be broken into two parts. One is where the unknown is in between the knowns, then it's simple to calculate the number of arrays,
The difference can only be 0,1 or 2. it can't be 3, because eg 2 0 5, then there is No value that gives the correct array. The input will always have a difference between the unknown as possible values. if the difference is 0, 2 0 2, then 3 values are possible, if the difference is 1, 2 0 3, then 1 and 3 are the only possible values, so 2 values possible. for the difference of 2, there is only 1 value so no change in the result is ok.

But the second case where the unknowns are in between unknowns is what troubles me.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

const int MOD   = 1e9 + 7;


int main() {

    int n,m;cin>>n>>m;
    vector<int> arr(n);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) cin>>arr[i];

    int res=1;

    if(arr[0]==0 && arr[1]!=0)
        res=(res%MOD*3)%MOD;
    if(arr[n-1]==0 && arr[n-2]!=0)
        res=(res%MOD*3)%MOD;

    //for unknowns between knowns
    for(int i=1;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==0 && arr[i-1]!=0 && arr[i+1]!=0)
        {
            int val=arr[i+1]-arr[i-1];
            if(val==0)
                res=(res%MOD*3)%MOD;
            else if(val==1)
                res=(res%MOD*2)%MOD;
        }
    }

    //for unknows between unknowns(I don't know how to approach this. Brute force will surely give TLE)
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int st=i;
        while(i<n && arr[i]==0)
            i++;

        if(arr[i]!=0) i--;

        if(i-st>=1)
        {
            if(st!=0 && i!=n-1)
            {

            }
        }

    }


    cout<<res;


    return 0;
}
```

for 2 0 2, output is 3 ([2 1 2][2 2 2][2 3 2])

I want to know how to solve the 2nd case of this problem, with continuous unknown values.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to approach or solve the 2nd case

Comment: I am already lost at case 1. why is it `res=(res%MOD*3)%MOD;` in both branches of the `if` (and then why  is there a `if/else if`? and what if `val` is not `0` or `1` ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear there, The difference can only be 0,1 or 2. it can't be 3, because eg 2 0 5, then there is No value that gives the correct array. The input will always have a difference between the unknown as possible values. if difference is 0, 2 0 2, then 3 values are possible, if difference is 1, 2 0 3, then 1 and 3 are the only possible values, so 2 values possible.

Comment: Do you mean with n elements or m elements? because m is just the max value the elements could have..
Also, one is *3, because as I told, if the difference is 0, we have 3 possibilities,and if 1, we have 2, so *2. 2 0 2 0 3, solution will be 3*2.., I mean *3 and *2 is just for 1st case

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 , can you explain a little more? what if first and last are just unknowns, like 3 0 0 0 0 5, then I will start from 3 and 5, then both are known, so increase start and last and numberofElements-2, then start and last are just 0 0 0 0, then what to do here ??Sorry, I just can't grasp it.

Comment: see answer.....

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 4):

1. The smaller problem you need to solve is:

   - Given the `first` and `last` element, how many ways are there to to
        fill the other elements?

     In different words: How many combinations of `M` terms of
        `-1`,`+0`,`+1` are there, that add up to `last-first`?

     A bit more formal, we want

     ```
            first + d_0 + d_1 + ... + d_M-1 == last
        ->  d_0 + d_1 + ... + d_M-2 == last-first
     ```

     This is a combinatorics problem. I'll leave it to you to find the
        right formula and just pick one example:

     ```
        M = 3
        first = 0
        last = 1

        solutions:
            0 +0+0+1 == 1 <- 3 different ways to sort the terms
            0 +1-1+1 == 1 <- 3 different ways sort the terms
     ```

     Write a function `find_combinations_between(int first,int last,int
        M);`.
   - The tiny problem:
        In case you have only `first` **or** `last` given, the solution is simply `3^M`.
2. Back to the original problem

   Once you can solve the smaller problem, getting arrays with known/unknown elements in the middle is straightforward.

   *Pseudocode*:

   ```
   int calculate( iterator begin, iterator end) {
       int count = 0;
       auto first = begin;
       auto last = begin;
       // find next known element
       while ( last != end && is_empty( last ) ) {
           ++last;
           ++count;
       }
       // there is none
       if ( last == end) return result * power_of_3( count );
       // ..or recurse to the next sub-interval
       return calculate(last,end) * find_combinations_between(first,last,count);
   }
   ```

   I think passing iterators can help for clarity a bit. The idea is to split the array into sub-intervals, such that always only first and last elements are known. `power_of_3` and `is_empty` is only used for readability, you could probably replace it with some other call or `== 0`, respectively. Take the code with a grain of salt, it is meant to outline the idea but may contain mistakes.
3. mod `1e7`

   Only when the algorithm itself is working I would incorporate the
   `%1e7` part, hence I ignored it for this answer.

---

**PS** I am not presenting you a full solution, but rather suggest you change perspective. Your "one unknown in between two knowns" case is a very special case, but you need an overall strategy first. If you follow my recipe then all the complexity is in one place: `find_combinations_between`. And most importantly, in that function, you can concentrate on the combinatorics problem, while it is irrelevant whether the elements are inside some array or whatever.

**PPS:** As already mentioned I did not present you a full solution. And I still do not feel like giving one. The above is only how to approach the problem in a different way, but how to actually solve it was left open. As per your request I will add a bit more clarification on how to tackle the `find_combinations_between`.

Some visualisation may help. As the solution only depends on the difference `last - first`, I use `first = 0` and `last = D`.

Lets first consider the case where `D==M`, ie the trivial case where we have to add `+1` on every element to reach the correct result:

```
0
 \
  \
   \
    \
     D
```

That was easy, right? There is only one solution. Now lets go just a tiny bit more compilcated: What if `D == M-1`? Then we have to add `+1` for all but one element. Possible solutions are

```
0        0        0         0
 \        \        \        |
  \        \        |        \
   \        |       \         \
   |        \        \         \
   D         D        D         D
```

ie exactly as many as there are free elements to choose. The same situation you have on the other end, when the only way to reach the right sum is to add `-1` on each element (or add `-1` on all but one).

It gets more complicated when `+1` and `-1` can be combined to get the right solution. The visualization above can still help for orientation. Think of all the paths that I didnt not draw in the above images, then you have a tree and need to find the number of possible paths from the root to a given leaf.

I don't know how to explain more without actually implementing it myself, which would mean starting to write code instead of writing the answer here ;). Hence I will again use an example and hope it helps you to find the solution.

Lets say the difference `last-first` is 2. Then first you need to find, for the given number of elements, lets say 4, all possible increments, that would be

```
+1 +1 +0 +0 = 2    // start with minimum number of +1s, ie 2 in this case
+1 +1 +1 -1 = 2    // next has 3x +1
                   // 4x +1 is not possible
```

Next you have to find all different permutations, that would be

```
+1 +1 +0 +0   // 4*3 because 
+1 +0 +1 +0   // 4 choices for the first +1
+1 +0 +0 +1   // x3 choices for the second
+0 +1 +1 +0
+0 +1 +0 +1
+0 +0 +1 +1

+1 +1 +1 -1  // 4 different ways to place the -1
....
```

In total that would be `12+4=16` different ways to add `+1`,`0` or `-1` to reach from any number `x` to `x+2` in `4` steps.

Comment: Just a doubt, so, what you are saying is I need to basically find the combinations of -1,0,1 that adds to give me last-first, in between known. So, for eg., I have 2 0 0 2. Then I need to find d1+d2=2-2 ? and d1 and d2 have to be combinations of -1,0 and 1 ???

Comment: @Behl exactly, this is what I try to say. Note that it does not matter that the `di` are differences between adjacent array elements, all you need is count how many combinations are there of `M` increments that add up to `first-last`

Comment: ok, so for 2 0 0 2, d1+d2==0, right? (with d1=-1,0,1 and d2=-1,0,1) 
So, -1+1, 1-1,0+0 so according to this only 3 arrays is possible or n+r-1Cr-1 ?? but the answer for this is 7([2 1 1 2][2 1 2 2][2 2 1 2][2 2 2 2][2 2 3 2] [2 3 2 2][2 3 3 2]? Maybe I misunderstood? please clarify this :)

Comment: @Behl I will extend the answer later

Comment: Thank you! just add a comment so that I could get notified.

Comment: @Behl I didnt really understand your (counter?) example. I added a bit more and another example, hope it is more clear now

Comment: See, Like you did for a case with 4 zeros and last-first=2, My counter was 2 0 0 2, so 2 zeros with diff=0. _ + _=0, According to what you wrote in your latest example, lets see the number of ways of filling _+_=0, right? 1-1, -1+1,0+0, So in total 3 ways. but correct output would be as I stated in previous comment 7. That's where I am having trouble understanding this way to approach the problem. Maybe I am still not getting it?

Comment: @Behl the problem is that I am always one off with the number of elements and increments. In the very last example it is not 4 unknowns but 3, eg for +1 +1 +0 +0 you get from 2 0 0 0 2 to 2 1 2 2 2 and in total the number of combinations is 16

Answer (score 1):

The simple implementation of the idea explained above using DP in c++
is as follows:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define mod 1000000007;
typedef long long ll;
ll const N = 1e5 + 5, M = 1e2 + 5;
ll n, m;
ll dp[N][M];
ll a[N];

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cin >> n >> m;

    for (ll i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    if (a[1] == 0)
        for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
            dp[1][i] = 1;
    else
        dp[1][a[1]] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            if (a[i] == 0 || j == a[i])
                dp[i][j] = (dp[i][j] + dp[i - 1][j - 1] + dp[i - 1][j] + dp[i - 1][j + 1]) % mod;
    }
    ll ans = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
    {
        ans += dp[n][i];
        ans %= mod;
    }
    cout << ans;
}
```